# Is there a way of having Wordpress render `the_category()` items as an (x)html list?

Tags: wordpress, xhtml, wordpress-theming, semantic-markup

I'm using the following to render `the_tags()` in Wordpress 2.9.2, currently developing a theme on localhost:

```
<?php the_tags('<ul class="postmetadata"><li>','</li><li>','</li></ul>'); ?>
```

and would like to have same -*near*-semantic- output from `the_category()`, which doesn't seem obviously attainable (having looked at the relevant [codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_category)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `the_category()` without any arguments, it will output an unordered list by default.

Comment: Up-voted and accepted. Man, I can't believe I didn't think to try that. *Or* that it wasn't (or doesn't seem to be) mentioned in the Codex...thanks! =)

Answer (score 1):

you can use wp_list_categories()